# Is the web performance of U.S. government websites open data?

Tags: usa, government

What open data is available about the number of visitors, type of browsers, etc. of U.S. Federal websites?  Is there both historical and real-time web analytics data available to the public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The US Government's [Digital Analytics Program](http://www.digitalgov.gov/services/dap/) (DAP) has been working on unified Web analytics for federal agencies for a couple of years

Recently they launched a nice web site that displays the top data:
https://analytics.usa.gov/

Philadelphia's
http://analytics.phila.gov/

Answer (score 3):

You can find some stats for individual sites by searching for the names of weblog analyzers that generate HTML reports and restrict by agency domain.  For example:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Anoaa.gov+webalizer

The current administration lifted the restriction on 'sharing data with third parties' if there was some sort of a benefit ... so some agencies started using Google Analytics or similar.

For example, see the following sections of NASA's [privacy policy](http://www.nasa.gov/about/highlights/HP_Privacy.html):

> Automatically Collected Information
>
> This website uses Google Analytics Premium. ...

...

> Providing Information to Third Parties
>
> NASA may share information with private organizations as part of a service that provides NASA users with increased capabilities or functionality on the site.

I see nothing in their policy that forbids them from sharing data if there *isn't* a benefit, so it's possible that a FOIA request might be able to get access to it.